# Subset distinct rows based on column value closest from 0

Tags: r, dplyr

I was wondering if someone had an efficient way to remove distinct rows based on a column value from the same dataframe. I want to keep the row in which the vlaue if this column is the closest from 0.

For exemple I have this dataframe :

```
df = data.frame(cond1=c("a","a","a","b","b"),cond2=c(1,1,2,3,3),value=c(10,-20,5,-5,12))
df
cond1 cond2 value
a     1     10
a     1     -20
a     2     5
b     3     -5
b     3     12
```

What I would like to obtain is removing rows with the same `cond1` and `cond2` with the farthest `value` from 0:

```
cond1 cond2 value
a     1     10
a     2     5
b     3     -5
```

In the cases `value` == `-value` I would ideally keep the two rows in my dataframe. Would you have any suggestion to overcome my problem ? I was thinking about combining `group_by`, `arrange`, and `filter` from `dplyr` but I struggle to make it work with my condition. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on the other answers which works for your example data. Note that another way of saying "the closest from 0" (I assume you mean the closest *to* 0) is simply the minimum of the absolute values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(cond1, cond2) %>% 
  filter(abs(value) == min(abs(value))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  cond1 cond2 value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1    10
2 a         2     5
3 b         3    -5
```

And if we alter `df` so that the second (a, 1) = -10 we get:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  cond1 cond2 value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1    10
2 a         1   -10
3 a         2     5
4 b         3    -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, we have :

```
df %>%
  mutate(dist = abs(0 - value)) %>%
  group_by(cond1, cond2) %>%
  filter(dist == min(dist)) %>%
  select(-dist)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   cond1, cond2 [3]
  cond1 cond2 value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1    10
2 a         2     5
3 b         3    -5
```

For the `-value == value` condition, This works as well:

Data:

```
structure(list(cond1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), cond2 = c(1, 
1, 2, 3, 3), value = c(10, -10, 5, -5, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

  cond1 cond2 value
1     a     1    10
2     a     1   -10
3     a     2     5
4     b     3    -5
5     b     3    12
```

Code:

```
  df %>%
  mutate(dist = abs(0 - value)) %>%
  group_by(cond1, cond2) %>%
  filter(dist == min(dist)) %>%
  select(-dist)
```

Output:

```
  cond1 cond2 value
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1    10
2 a         1   -10
3 a         2     5
4 b         3    -5
```